# update date.js and remove document.write

Tags: javascript, file, date, document.write

I would like help to update this date.js code to remove the document.write statements as it is now obsolete

```
 if (Date.parse(document.lastModified) != 0) {
  var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
  var monthName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
   "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
  document.write(monthName[modiDate.getMonth()] + " ");
  document.write(modiDate.getDate() + ", " + modiDate.getFullYear());
  }
```

What do I put in place of document.write(...... please

the javascript code produces a (File) Updated on September 12, 2019 at the bottom of the web page via this code snipit

```
 <p>Updated <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/jsscripts/date.js"> </script>
```

Thanks Mark

Comment: what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574098/is-document-write-actually-deprecated

Comment: Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), which is the closest equivalent replacement of `document.write` together with [`currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) to get the HTML element of the script, that's being evaluated.

```html
<p>Updated
  <script>
    var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
    var monthName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
      "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var text = monthName[modiDate.getMonth()] + " ";
    text += modiDate.getDate() + ", " + modiDate.getFullYear();
    document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', text);
  </script>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for yoru feedback

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe.

It'll update all elements with the `class` `documentLastModified`.

```html
<p>Updated <span class="documentLastModified" /></p>

<script>
var modiDate = new Date(document.lastModified);
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.documentLastModified')).forEach((el) => {
  el.innerHTML = modiDate.toDateString();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementById` and `toLocaleDateString`

```js
// date.js

document.getElementById('updated-date').textContent = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { /* new Date(document.lastModified)... */
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric'
})
```

```html
<p>Updated <span id="updated-date"></span></p>

<!-- end of body 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/jsscripts/date.js">-->
```